# php tag within css does not work

Tags: php, css, mysqli

I have a code in which i want to show all the categories from database table. But it only gives the first row data and it is also not displaying the image which i have given in my css.

**Code**

```
 <div id="col1">
 <?php
  $query="Select * from category";
  $res=mysqli_query($con,$query);
  while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
  ?>
  <a class="maskA" href= <?=$row['pages'];?> >
  <span class="span2"><?=$row['cat_name'];?> Collection</span></a>
  </div>
```

**css**

```
    #col1{
    background:url(<?= "images/ ".$row["poster"];  ?>);
    background-size:100% 100%;
    }
    <?php
     }
     ?>
```

Comment: css files are not normally processed by PHP (and even if they were, the above attempt does not make sense and would still not work). Why don't you simply use inline styles for the background URL?

Comment: well i tried `<div  class="col-sm-4 masking" style="background-size: 100% 100%; background:url("images/<?php $row["poster"];?>");  >` this!! but it also don't work

Comment: "don't work" is not enough information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To put PHP in a CSS file, make it a PHP file.

The only thing you need to do extra is tell the receiving end it's a css file by using `header` as the very first thing in the file.

```php
<?php header('content-type: text/css'); ?>
```